# How can I add an event listener for multiple buttons with same class name?

Tags: javascript, listener

I'm building a decision tree in JavaScript. I do not have jQuery available to me for this project.

I would like to be able to have buttons, placed anywhere in the decision tree (Hidden or displayed anywhere on the page), with the same class name.  The listener on the JS side would then run a function.

Here is what I am using for and ID based listener.  It works well but I need to be able to have multiple buttons with the same class or name available. Although I have seen examples of this, I cannot get it to function properly.

```
function q1a1() {
var q1a1button = document.getElementById("q1answer1");
        if(q1a1button.addEventListener){
q1a1button.addEventListener("click", function() { q1answer1();}, false);
        } else if(q1a1button.attachEvent){
q1a1button.attachEvent("onclick", function() { q1answer1();});
}
};

if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener("load", q1a1, false);
        } else if(window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent("onload", q1a1);
        } else{
    document.addEventListener("load", q1a1, false);                
}

function q1answer1() {          

//DO SOME STUFF
                                            }
```

This also needs to work in as many versions of IE as possible. For single class handling I'm using querySelectorAll.

Comment: just use querySelectorAll() to iterate through the elements with that class, more-or-less wrapping that loop around the code you already have. you can also attach a single event to the body, and look at (e.target||e.srcElement).className to decide how to handle the event at invocation time.

Comment: querySelectorAll works in ie8. If you need to support anything below that, I feel sorry for you. Just iterate through the array of elements, adding an event listener for each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are really looking for is [JavaScript Event Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). In your case, you have BUTTON elements, which I'm going to assume are `<button>` tags. Now you want to know when one of those buttons was clicked and then run a function:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent("onclick", handleClick);
}

function handleClick(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    event.target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    var element = event.target;

    // Climb up the document tree from the target of the event
    while (element) {
        if (element.nodeName === "BUTTON" && /foo/.test(element.className)) {
            // The user clicked on a <button> or clicked on an element inside a <button>
            // with a class name called "foo"
            doSomething(element);
            break;
        }

        element = element.parentNode;
    }
}

function doSomething(button) {
    // do something with button
}
```

Anywhere on the page that a `<button class="foo">...</button>` element appears, clicking it, or any HTML tag inside of it, will run the `doSomething` function.

Update: Since Event Delegation is used, only a single click handler is registered on the document object. If more `<button>`s are created as a result of an AJAX call, you don't have to register click handlers on those new `<button>`s since we take advantage of the click event bubbling up from the element the user clicked on to the document object itself.

Comment: jQuery's `on` method is very handy, but for those of us without jQuery or don't want to use it, I wrote [Oxydizr](https://github.com/gburghardt/oxydizr), which utilizes HTML5 data-* attributes. It allows you to completely decouple behavior, markup and style.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt if you want the button that is clicked color changes how we can achieve that without unique id or class name?

Comment: I was looking a way to extract the target of event. Your code showed me how to do it. Thanks a lot. This was super helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have jquery:

```
if (document.body.addEventListener){
    document.body.addEventListener('click',yourHandler,false);
}
else{
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick',yourHandler);//for IE
}

function yourHandler(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.className.match(/keyword/))
    {
        //an element with the keyword Class was clicked
    }
}
```

If you use a cross browser library like jquery:

HTML:

```
<div class="myClass">sample</div>
<div class="myClass">sample 2</div>
```

JS:

```
function theFuncToCall(event){
  //func code
}

$(document).on('click', '.myClass', theFuncToCall);
```

Comment: jQuery is not available from within this organization. (I cannot use it) hence the frustration and new learning curve. :)

Comment: Obligatory link to [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".MyClassName");
var i = 0, length = buttons.length;
for (i; i < length; i++) {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            // use keyword this to target clicked button
        });
    } else {
        buttons[i].attachEvent("onclick", function() {
            // use buttons[i] to target clicked button
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit overkill, but it should show you ways you could structure your code in a "modern" way even if you're still targeting old browsers

1. Write code to add event listeners so there is minimal difference between new and old browsers

   ```
   var listen = (function () { // will return the handler for use in unlisten
       if (window.addEventHandler) {
           return function (node, type, handler) {
               node.addEventListener(type, handler);
               return handler;
           };
       } else if (window.attachEvent) {
           return function (node, type, handler) {
               var fn = function (e) {
                   if (!e) {
                       e = window.event;
                   }
                   if (!e.target && e.srcElement) {
                       e.target = e.srcElement;
                   }
                   return handler.call(this, e);
               };
               node.attachEvent('on' + type, fn);
               return fn;
           };
       } else {
           throw new Error('Events not supported in this environment');
           // or
        // return function ... node['on' + type] = function () { ... };
       }
   }());
   ```

   and if you'd like the reverse, too

   ```
   var unlisten = (function () { // use handler given by listen
       if (window.removeEventListener) {
           return function (node, type, handler) {
               node.removeEventListener(type, handler);
           };
       } else if (window.detachEvent) {
           return function (node, type, handler) {
               node.detachEvent('on' + type, handler);
           };
       } else {
           throw new Error('Events not supported in this environment');
           // or
        // return function ... node['on' + type] = null;
       }
   }());
   ```
2. Write your click handler

   ```
   function clickHandler(e) {
       // do stuff
   }
   ```
3. Wrap your click handler in a function to choose only clicks on buttons with the right class

   ```
   function wrappedClickHandler(e) {
       var tokens, i;
       if (e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT' && e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') {
           return;
       }
       tokens = (e.target.className || '').split(' ');
       for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
           if (tokens[i] === 'theClassTokenWeWant') {
               return clickHandler.call(this, e);
               // or
            // return clickHandler.call(e.target, e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add this as a listener to a common ancestor node

   ```
   var h = listen(document, 'click', wrappedClickHandler);
   // .. later, if desired
   unlisten(document, 'click', h);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Would the simpler way of writing the event delegation function be to add it to the container of the buttons? For example,

```
// Select Container Element
const questionContainer = document.querySelector(".container");

// Listen For Clicks Within Container
questionContainer.onclick = function (event) {
    // Prevent default behavior of button
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store Target Element In Variable
    const element = event.target;

    // If Target Element Is a Button
    if (element.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
        // Event Code
    }
}
```