# How to handle event from multiple buttons of same name

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-handling, element

I am working on a small practice program where I have 3 white boxes in a row.  My goal is (using Javascript) for any of the boxes to change from white to red when the mouse is over the box, and then to turn yellow when the mouse comes off the box.  The code below works on the initial box but not on the other two.  When I put the mouse over the other boxes, it doesn't change them but it does change the color on the inital box.  I've looked at similar questions but most of them involve jquery, which I am not using.  I've done some research and possible solutions might involve using addEventListener or using "this".  I don't want to give different names to the button id's and write additional procedures based on them -- that would be inefficient.  I know there must be a more efficient way.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Whiteboxes 5</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    function changeColorOnMouseOver()
     {
    var control=document.getElementById("btn");
    control.style.background='red';
     }
     function changeColorOnMouseOut()
     {
    var control=document.getElementById("btn");
    control.style.background='yellow';
     }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app5.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="button" value="" id="btn"
      onmouseover="changeColorOnMouseOver()"
      onmouseout="changeColorOnMouseOut()"/>

    <input type="button" value="" id="btn"
      onmouseover="changeColorOnMouseOver()"
      onmouseout="changeColorOnMouseOut()"/>

    <input type="button" value="" id="btn"
      onmouseover="changeColorOnMouseOver()"
      onmouseout="changeColorOnMouseOut()"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `this` reference like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Whiteboxes 5</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    function changeColorOnMouseOver(control)
     {
         control.style.background='red';
     }
     function changeColorOnMouseOut(control)
     {
         control.style.background='yellow';
     }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app5.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="button" value="" id="btn1"
      onmouseover="changeColorOnMouseOver(this)"
      onmouseout="changeColorOnMouseOut(this)"/>

    <input type="button" value="" id="btn2"
      onmouseover="changeColorOnMouseOver(this)"
      onmouseout="changeColorOnMouseOut(this)"/>

    <input type="button" value="" id="btn3"
      onmouseover="changeColorOnMouseOver(this)"
      onmouseout="changeColorOnMouseOut(this)"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

In html ID's should be unique.  No 2 elements should have the same ID. `this` will refer to the caller element.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding.  This works and it helps me to see now how to pass the current element to the function using "this".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery and changing the ID to CLALL.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Whiteboxes 5</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".btn").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
      },function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
      });
    });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app5.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="button" value="" class="btn"/>

    <input type="button" value="" class="btn"/>

    <input type="button" value="" class="btn"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  When I start learning jQuery I will refer back to this.

Answer (score 0):

Per the HTML5 spec, id attributes must be unique in the document.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

If you just change the id attributes to class attributes, you can use the following answer and tweak it a little bit to do what you want (change the event from click to mouseover, etc).

[JavaScript: Event listener for multiple buttons with same class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835150/javascript-event-listener-for-multiple-buttons-with-same-class-name)