# Multiple buttons with the same class name but only the first one works

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm fairly new to JS and I currently working on the front-end of a very basic ecommerce page as a personal project.

Here's my question, all the "items" on the page are exact the same aside from their name. When I click on "buy", I'd like to send the name of the respective item to the cart. However every time I click on any buy button, instead of sending the title of the item I just clicked, it always sends the "Item 1".

I've been trying to figure this out for sometime now but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance!

--HTML--

```
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <p id="logo">eCommerce</p>
        <div id="cart">
            <img src="icons/shoppingcart.svg" alt="cart" id="cart-icon">
            <a href="#" id="cart-quantity"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cart-container">
        <div id="cart-content">
            <p id="cart-items">Your cart is empty</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="items">
        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 1</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 2</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 3</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 4</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 5</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 6</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 7</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 8</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

--JS--

```
/* global variables */
const itemsForSale = document.querySelector('#items')
const cartQuantity = document.querySelector('#cart-quantity')
const cartContent = document.querySelector('#cart-icon')
const cartItems = document.querySelector('#cart-content');

/* cart array */
const cart = []


/* -------------------------------------------------------- 
functions -------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------- */


/* add to cart function */
const addToCartBtn = document.querySelector('.addToCartBtn');

addToCartBtn.onclick = function () {

    /* items in cart */
    const itemName = document.querySelector('.product-name').innerHTML;

    cart.push(itemName)
    console.log(cart)

    /* add item name to the cart */
    for(i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector('#cart-items').textContent = `${cart[i]}`
    }

    /* quantity of items in cart */
    cartSum = cart.length
    cartQuantity.textContent = cartSum

};



/* show/hide item content */
cartContent.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(cartItems.style.display == 'none') {
        cartItems.style.display = 'flex';
    } else {
        cartItems.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only returns the first match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add an event listener for multiple buttons with same class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835150/how-can-i-add-an-event-listener-for-multiple-buttons-with-same-class-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `querySelector` returns the first instance of the element in the DOM that corresponds to the class you are looking for. To fix this, first of all, I listened to the event of clicking all the buttons with `querySelectorAll`, and in the function itself, I searched for `.product-name` according to the parent `closest` to the button that has the class `product`

```js
/* global variables */
const itemsForSale = document.querySelector('#items')
const cartQuantity = document.querySelector('#cart-quantity')
const cartContent = document.querySelector('#cart-icon')
const cartItems = document.querySelector('#cart-content');

/* cart array */
const cart = []


/* -------------------------------------------------------- 
functions -------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------- */
/* add to cart function */
const addToCartBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCartBtn');

addToCartBtn.forEach(btn => {
    btn.onclick = function (e) {

    /* items in cart */
    const itemName = e.target.closest('.product').querySelector('.product-name').innerHTML;

    cart.push(itemName)
    console.log(cart)

    /* add item name to the cart */
    for(i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector('#cart-items').textContent = `${cart[i]}`
    }

    /* quantity of items in cart */
    cartSum = cart.length
    cartQuantity.textContent = cartSum

    };
})





/* show/hide item content */
cartContent.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(cartItems.style.display == 'none') {
        cartItems.style.display = 'flex';
    } else {
        cartItems.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <p id="logo">eCommerce</p>
        <div id="cart">
            <img src="icons/shoppingcart.svg" alt="cart" id="cart-icon">
            <a href="#" id="cart-quantity"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cart-container">
        <div id="cart-content">
            <p id="cart-items">Your cart is empty</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="items">
        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 1</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 2</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 3</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 4</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 5</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 6</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 7</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://mattgreenhalgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Placeholder_1080p.png" alt="product-img">
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name">Item 8</p>
                <p class="product-price">Price: $100</p>
            </div>
            <button class="addToCartBtn">add to cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Only had time to check out the code now. I'm getting the following error when I click on any buy button: Uncaught TypeError: e.closest is not a function at btn.onclick. Any idea of what might be causing it?

Comment: @dhspecialized I've edited the code for you to run here, if it answers your question I'd appreciate it if you marked it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, simple and do the work perfectly :)

```
let AddTocartButton = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCartBtn');
let ProductNames = document.querySelectorAll('.product-name');
let cart = document.querySelector('#cart');
AddTocartButton.forEach((element , index) => {
    element.onclick = function () {
        let CartItem = document.createElement('a');
        let itemName = ProductNames[index].textContent;
        CartItem.textContent = itemName;
        cart.appendChild(CartItem);
    }
});
```